# Web application with a continuously running Java program

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

Currently I have a Java socket program that needs to be continuously running (monitoring a device), and I want to write a web application to read and write to the socket program.

My current plan is to use servlet and JSP, using JSP to create webpage to communicate with servlet which creates another socket to read and write to the Java socket program and then end. Or should I create a thread for the servlet from the Java program, or create a thread for the Java program from the servlet but then the servlet would be continuously running which isn't a good idea.

My main question is, is there any other way I can achieve this? I want to use a relatively more efficient method to do this. The JSP website style I found were quite classic look, I want a more modern looking style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your scenario, I think it could be simpler to implement directly a web socket into your monitoring program? One of the most used Java web sockets frameworks seems this one: http://jwebsocket.org/

[EDIT]

As to the website style, it does not really depend on the technology behind, you can achieve what you want with the proper CSS skills.

Comment: Thanks, I am reading on Websocket now, do you know what does it take to run websocket on a web server? any software I need to install on web server?

Comment: a problem i see regarding websocket, the older browsers such as ie8, 9 doesnt support it, does that means those user won't be able to access the web application?

Comment: I was thinking of websockets to allow direct communication between your client and your monitoring program, without the need to add anything to your webserver. As to older browsers, jwebsocket has a Flash fallback for those browsers that don't directly support it.